# group without involution is 2-divisible

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be an arbitrary torsion group without involutions. Show that $G$ is 2-divisible.

I think it is enough to show $G$=$2G$ but i can't show why $2G$ can't be proper subgroups of $G$ ?

Please give me Hint not all answer .

Comment: Can you solve the problem for $G = Z_n$ with $n$ odd?

Comment: yes i can but how i can extend it to arbitrary torsion . I think it is easy if group is abelian but it is not so what is your idea ?

Comment: Your torsion group is a union of groups of the type described by j.p.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen know it abelian case group is direct sum of p-groups but i dont know non-abelian case if you have link about your statement could you send ?

Comment: No, I don't have a link. It is a useful exercise to show that your group is a union of cyclic subgroups.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen i think it is like prüfer groups .Thanks for your comment i will try it.

Comment: @rmznyzgyr You don't have to prove that it is a direct sum, just a set-theoretic union.